# Unable to select checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am unable to click checkbox

Here is [my project link](http://52.90.124.165:8000/product-details/1000050)

I need to click (Active) Checkbox's (next to size's) present in bottom of the page which has defined in table.

I tried with,

```
//label[@style='margin-left:11px']: (It is not working)
```

I am getting an error stating `'Unable to find an element'`

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Are you trying to click a checkbox for a certain size?

Comment: Yes @Grasshopper, I need to click any of the size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to click the checkbox next to size '2XL' try this xpath --

`"//td[normalize-space(.)='2XL']/preceding-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']"`

Comment: Hi i tried with,                                                       element(by.xpath("//td[normalize-space(.)='2XL']/preceding-sibling::td/input[@type='checkbox']"));  But it is not working showing as unable to find an element error

Comment: A word of caution : you should n't share your project links directly, instead share the html equivalent for the problem.

Comment: @Grasshopper, Kushal,  Its not working , Element not found error appeaars

Comment: It works in the browser console. Have you tried waiting for the element to be visible. Try a browser sleep and then use the xpath. If it works then refine the code by removing the sleep and adding an ExpectedCondition for visibility.

Comment: It's Working fine now , I used as below                                                                     //td[normalize-space(.)='2XL']/preceding-sibling::td/label[@for='checkbox1']     Thanks @Grasshopper, Whats ur mail id?